# I want to show the associative array values one by one in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, associative-array

```
$order=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order_details` WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$orderArray=mysql_fetch_array($order);

$productId=explode(',',$orderArray['product_id']);
$productId=(array_values($productId));
$quantityId=explode(',',$orderArray['quantity']);
$quantityId=(array_values($quantityId));
print_r($quantityId);

$i=0;
foreach($productId as $id)  
{   
    $i++;
    //echo "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id";
    $productId=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id");  
    $productArray=mysql_fetch_array($productId);
?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
          <td>
              <?php echo $productArray['name'];?>
          </td>
          <td>
              <?php echo $productArray['price'];?>
          </td>
          <td>
              <?php 
                  for($j=0;$j<count($quantityId);$j++){
                      echo $quantityId[$j];
                  }   

              ?>
          </td>
          <td>
              <?php 

                      echo $orderArray['price'];
              ?>
          </td>
      </tr>   
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to show the quantity one by one the inside the loop and as there is a count function inside the loop it prints the total quantity inside

**My output:**

```
Sl No.  Name             Price      Quantity    
1   watches2              100            12                                 
2   pens1                 100            12
```

**desired output:**

```
Sl No.  Name             Price      Quantity    
1   watches2            100              1                                  
2   pens1               100              2
```

Comment: Specify what array output you are getting and what you want ? Show us your exact output ?

Comment: You need a while loop. and use mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: if i print the $quantityId array,the output is Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ),so i got the array as expected from database,but i want to loop through it one by one not at once,as is the case with me.

Comment: hi ravi,could u help me with the code,how would i use while loop as the product ids are fetched from the database.Your help will save my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
<?php

$order=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `order_details` WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'") or die(mysql_error());
// Use mysql_fetch_assoc here
$orderArray=mysql_fetch_assoc($order);
// No need to do explode.  assign directly to query
$productId=$orderArray['product_id'];
// no need of below line explode set array index from 0 same as array_values does
//$productId=(array_values($productId));
$quantityId=explode(',',$orderArray['quantity']);
// no need of below line explode set array index from 0 same as array_values does
//$quantityId=(array_values($quantityId));

//foreach($productId as $id){   // No need for this loop

// Use IN in mysql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN ($productId)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}   

// Use mysql_fetch_assoc here
for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); ++$i){   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['price']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$quantityId[$i]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$orderArray['price']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";    
}
//}
```

You can also use while loop as below:-

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['price']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$quantityId[$counter]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>".$orderArray['price']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    $counter++; // or $counter = $counter + 1;
}
```

**Warning**:-

> mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: he set it as a derivative of `$orderArray=mysql_fetch_array($order);` which you do not have in your code

Comment: @RamRaider: I have edited my answer. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: foreach($quantityId a $Id){
                echo $Id.'<br>';
            }this gives a server error 500

Comment: Please post your desired output in your question.

Comment: Yes ravi.By the way thanks a ton for replying me so fast.thanks again

Comment: Write echo $i; inside loop check you get 1 and 2 both or 1 and 1 again

Comment: its 0 which i have already checked while printing out the serial number,that s what is causing the issue.Thnx for help again.

Comment: yes i've printed $i inside loop it prints 0 and the quantity is 1 for both <td>'s.$i is not incremented i'm looking into it

Comment: Very strange. Let me know when you resolved it. If not then find some way to catch screenshot and send me :)

Comment: $i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
//for ($i = 0; $i<=count($row);$i++) { 
         //echo $i;
         echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$i. "</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['name']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['price']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>".$quantityId[$i]. "</td>";
          echo "<td>".$orderArray['price']."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
         ++$i;
         // 
        }why the value of $i is not incrmented inside the while loop

Comment: Check my updated answer.If that solution not working then provid me screenshot.

Comment: Sl No. Name Price Quantity TOTAL
0        rooy        200           1           3208
0      Blue      1000           1           3208
0     Div88      2008           1           3208

Comment: $counter = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".++$counter. "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['name']. "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['price']. "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$quantityId[$counter]. "</td>";
         echo "<td>".$orderArray['price']."</td>";
         echo "</tr>"; 
            $counter++; // or $counter = $counter + 1;
        }

Comment: @andy. You can do your functionality without foreach loop. see my updated answer. I have optimized code. Try both while loop and for loop to get data. While loop will also work. Let me know if you have any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use for loop just to print quantity..
just use code as below

```
  <?php echo $quantityId[$i]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

";
                                    echo "".++$i. "";
                                    echo "".$row['name']. "";
                                    echo "".$row['price']. "";
                                    echo "".$quantityId[$counter]. "";
                                    echo "".$orderArray['price']."";
                                    echo ""; 

                                }
                                $counter = $counter + 1; // or $counter = $counter + 1;
                        }//foreach ends
                        ?>

Comment: please look at [answer]. Code only answers aren't useful for the community. Format your code for better readability